# C# SQLite некоторые команды Delete в цикле не выполняются

Tags: c#, sqlite

Есть таблица Занятий, пользователь выбирает несколько строк в граф. интерфейсе и нажимает кнопку "Удалить". Выполняется метод `deleteLessons(List<Lesson> lessons)`, который поэлементно удаляет записи с БД.

```
    public static void deleteLessons(List<Lesson> lessons)
    {
        connection.Open();//открывает БД
        foreach (Lesson l in lessons)
        {
            //удаляет запись
            new SQLiteCommand(String.Format("DELETE FROM Lesson WHERE id = {0};", l.id), connection).ExecuteReader();
        }
        connection.Close();//закрывает БД
    }
```

Все предельно просто. Но на деле удаляются почему-то не все записи. Если попытаться удалить сразу 10 - то удалится 5 или 7 или 8 например. Каждый раз что-то не удаляет. Мне кажется, что это из-за того, что предыдущий запрос не успевает выполниться пока следующий уже вызывается. Что в этом случае делать?

Comment: Дык может быть дело в том, что на некоторые записи ссылаются другие таблицы внешними ключами, вот и не удаляются записи? Вот если на второй раз удалять одну и ту же запись - то удалится или нет?

Comment: @A K, да, эта в этой таблице почти все поля - внешние ключи. Но дело явно не в данных. Если взять 2 одинаковые БД и выполнить удаление, то удалятся разные записи.

Comment: А почему `ExecuteReader()` если вы ничего не читаете? Там должно быть `ExecuteNonQuery()` вообще то. Этот метод вам вернет 1 если строка была удалена успешно.

Comment: @Bulson, сейчас попробую, просто у меня там очень много команд в разные таблицы и для удобства я вынес функцию execute с ExecuteReader() для красивой работы. Подумал, что хуже не будет, если что-то будет возвращаться.

Comment: Для удаление нескольких строк я бы сделал иначе: в цикле сформировал все нужные sql команды, то есть по числу нужных удалений такое число сформированных sql команд с уже вставленными Id. Потом бы открыл соединение с базой выполнил все эти команды последовательно. Потом закрыл бы соединение.

Comment: @Bulson, у меня по сути так и работает. Один раз открывается соединение, в цикле для каждой записи формируется строка и делается запрос.

Comment: @Bulson, так я же и говорю, я один раз открываю, выполняю цикл, затем закрываю

Comment: Проверил ваш код на своей БД - работает нормально, удаляет все записи с указанными id. Следовательно, проблема где-то в другом месте.

Comment: _вынес функцию execute с ExecuteReader() для красивой работы. Подумал, что хуже не будет_ - если бы я был вашим начальником, я бы подумал, что хуже не будет, и уволил такого работника... Ибо нефиг :).

Comment: Замечания по коду: используйте `ExecuteNonQuery`, используйте параметры, объект `SQLiteCommand` тоже нужно диспозить (используйте `using`), не используйте глобальное или статическое соединение.

Comment: А что если обернуть ваш код в одну транзакцию? Хинт: `connection.BeginTransaction()` и не забудьте `transaction.Commit`.